# 500 internal server error in react js connect with mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I get 500 internal server error in react hs connect with mongodb, I am use axios for connecting and I get this type of error I am try so many times but all time I get this, please help me how to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is impossible to get any help without include the actual code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Is the server started?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Make sure that the IP address of Mongodb can have access from anywhere.

Step 2: Make sure that you put the username and password correctly in when you copied the string for Mongodb.

I wanted to copy the produced password and I tried to press the show-button and I copied the String by myself (without the copy-button).
After that, I updated my user (you might forget this because it's at the bottom of page)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).